# What is the reference behind "...Gold Sakaki or a Silver Sakaki" that Io mentions?

Tags: acchi-kocchi

In episode 6, Io asks everyone the following question:

> Was the Sakaki you dropped in this pool a Gold Sakaki, or a Silver Sakaki?

What is this in reference to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in reference to one of [Aesop's Fables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesop%27s_Fables), ["The Honest Woodman."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Honest_Woodman)

> The Greek version of the story tells of a woodcutter who accidentally dropped his axe into a river and, because this was his only means of livelihood, sat down and wept. Taking pity on him, the god Hermes (also known as Mercury) dived into the water and returned with a golden axe. "Was this what you had lost?", Hermes asked, but the woodcutter said it was not, and returned the same answer when a silver axe was brought to the surface. Only when his own tool is produced does he claim it. Impressed by his honesty, the god allows him to keep all three. Hearing of the man's good fortune, an envious neighbor threw his own axe into the river and wailed for its return. When Hermes appeared and offered him a golden axe, the man greedily claimed it but was denied both that and the return of his own axe.